# What is the optimum length of abstinence for maximum ejaculation volume in humans?

Tags: human-biology, statistics

There have been papers discussing this, and whether the abstinence period should be 1 week, 2 weeks or other [1, 2]. Some think the time to maximum ejaculation volume is even longer than this.

1. doi: [10.1530/jrf.0.0570391](http://dx.doi.org/10.1530/jrf.0.0570391)
2. PMID: [7114956](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7114956)

Comment: This value is going to be species-specific (cf. mouse vs. elephant), so in its current version your question is too broad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There don't appear to be many robust studies on this, but this study by De Longe *et al* in 2004 suggests that, whilst the volume of the ejaculate is increased after 5-days of abstinence (in most participants), for many this did not increase further after 8-days [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtB77.png)].

Here are the 11 participant included (along the x-axis), and for each participant there are four coloured boxes:  dark blue, day 1 (corresponds to 24 hours' abstinence); red, day 3 (corresponds to 3 days' abstinence); yellow, day 5 (corresponds to 5 days' abstinence); light blue, day 8 (corresponds to 8 days' abstinence).

[image]

This study has a very small sample size, and really shows how the variability between people is massive. There could be *many* other factors affecting individuals, from smoking and drinking behaviours, to exercise and stress.

What seems much clearer is that sperm *concentration* increases with abstinence [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw80N.gif)]. This study included 27 men and did not specifically ask them to remain abstinent for periods of time, but asked them how long. The average abstinence is about 2-days.

[image]

I could not find any study which investigated abstinence for longer periods - but there are undoubtedly more that I did not see.

1. De Longe, *at al*. 2004. **Influence of the abstinence period on human sperm quality**. *Fertility and Sterility* (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.fertnstert.2004.03.014)
2. Carlsen, *et al*, 2004. **Effects of ejaculatory frequency and season on variations in semen quality**. *Fertility and Sterility* (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.fertnstert.2004.01.039)

Comment: Very interesting findings.